# What is a suitable type (from the typing module) for list, tuple or set in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, python-typing

Some that I've encountered:

1. typing.ItemsView
2. typing.AbstractSet
3. typing.Collection
4. typing.Container

Which one do you think is most suitable?

Comment: Depends on what you need. If you *specifically* need one of those three types, using `typing.Union[list,tuple,set]`. Otherwise, consider how the argument will actually be used and choose the least restrictive ABC that supports your intended use.

Comment: You have also ```typing.List```, ```typing.Set```, ```typing.FrozenSet``` and ```typing.Tuple```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as mentioned in the comments [typing.union](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Union) is a nice option, also as mentioned in the comments try and see what one "implements" what your function uses.

I think [typing.Collection](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Collection) is the one that covers all of them, but you might be doing something that only needs [typing.Iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Iterable).

without knowing more about what you are doing it is hard to say.

Comment: sadly `str` is also a `Collection` and `Iterable` and `Container`